# Improve form validation for mod messages by rejecting unfilled template tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderation, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

When a moderator intends to contact a user about questionable behavior on a site, the moderator can choose from a set of message templates for addressing common behavior patterns.

Some of these templates contain `{todo:}` template tags that are meant to be, well, filled in. Currently, submitting a message with any of these template tags still in the message causes it to be sent anyway, with that template tag plainly visible both in the on-site message and in the email message, which can be quite embarrassing (for lack of a better word).

It would be cool if moderator messages could be validated for the presence of template tags and summarily rejected if any of them were found, in case a moderator neglected to fill in important information such as the duration of an account suspension.

Comment: I know this used to work (not submit the form if there was still `{todo:}` text in the body) in some of the messages.  Do I have any volunteers for some science?

Comment: @BilltheLizard Feel free.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: I can, on meta :P

Comment: Go for it (as long as you don't *actually* suspend me of course)

Comment: I just suspended @Ninefingers for sockpuppet upvoting (here on Meta) and the form automatically filled in the `{todo:suspend} days` with `7 days`.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Very interesting. We could use some validation for the rest of the template tags, though. I don't think all of them are auto-filled.

Comment: I got the same result with the "consistently low quality" message.  It auto-filled the `{todo:suspend} days` with `30 days`.  I'm looking for others that have text to replace.

Comment: Wow I've had a busy day. First sock puppeting, then consistently low quality questions and answers!

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Message/suspend me for "something else"? Almost the whole thing is template tags, and those aren't auto-filled (unless they wrote and hid an AI behind the scenes or something).

Comment: The "something else..." message does prompt you to fill those `{todo}` items in if you try to submit without replacing them.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Oh, it does? Well, then. Post that as an answer? Or I'll delete this...

Comment: @Ninefingers Thanks for volunteering to be the guinea pig.  Now you seriously can't break any rules on Meta because the next suspension will be 365 days.  ;)

Comment: @Bill ok. But can you make it something more interesting like rule violations or to calm down next time please? If I'm gonna be a test troll, I want to look and act the part! ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried all three of the messages that have `{todo}` items embedded in the body here on Meta.  Two of them automatically insert the suspension length for you in place of the `{todo:suspend}` placeholder, and the last one prompts you if it finds any `{todo}` placeholders when you try and submit the form.

This may be browser-specific, so I'll add that I'm on Firefox on Windows XP Pro.

---

I re-ran these tests on Stack Overflow (using [Tim Post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) as a guinea pig this time), and I got the same results.  The `{todo}` text is either auto-replaced or a prompt tells me that I forgot to fill one in.

Comment: And here, Meta Police Force, is your daily dose of science. Have a great day.

Comment: ***Windows XP Pro???***

Comment: @Won't It's a work machine.  I was wondering how long it would take anyone to react to that.  :)

Comment: "Uh, boss, someone accidentally shot my machine with a destructive device.  Can I have another?"

Comment: @Won't You should see the machines that are piling up to be thrown out.  Nobody will even steal them.

Comment: It's been this way for a long long time. Good idea but long implemented already

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: [The dev team thinks of *everything*.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheDevTeamThinksOfEverything)

Comment: @JeffAtwood Nice implementation on the first two that just fill in the known values for us instead of prompting for input.