# Send suspension notices & mod messages to Global Inbox as well

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, global-inbox, account-suspension, moderator-messages

I realized that Mod messages/suspension notices are not delivered to the inbox.

I'm not sure why that's so. With most activity being delivered to the Inbox, something as important as Mod messages should also be delivered.

You may argue that the suspension notice is sent to email - but if there's no email address provided, once a Mod Message has been issued, if there is an overlay(I've never been suspended, so don't know), dismissing the overlay would mean that there's no way to read the mod message.

Comment: Isn't the bright orange banner at the top of the page enough, or do the recipients of mod messages not get that the same as mods do when other mods *send* them?

Comment: The only way to find out is to suspend yourself... FOR SCIENCE!

Comment: [science](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129878/137537)

Comment: @casperOne They get the banner, but when it's dismissed, it's gone forever.

Comment: Banner blindness... What was *that?*

Comment: @yoda FOR SCIENCE!